# Is it possible to set bits of a void* value without type casting it to an int or char?

Tags: c, mmap, void-pointers

I am working on a project that requires me to allocate some space using the `mmap` function and I need to create a bitmap in the beginning of the allocated space. The bitmap shows which sections are occupied and which sections are free, sections being divided into 8 byte words. Each bit in the bitmap indicates whether its corresponding word is free or occupied. I am pointing to the space via a `void*` but I can not individually set the bits without making a type cast into an int. I know that I can set the bits in bulks of 32 by setting each int to -1, since my compiler uses 2's compliment but different compilers have different implementations. It also has the problem of using unnecessary bits if the number of words is not a multiple of 32.

Is it possible to set those bits one by one without type casting them?

Comment: Please [edit] and show relevant some code rather than describing it.

Comment: Raw binary data should always be accessed through an unsigned character pointer: `unsigned char*` or `uint8_t*`. Using a pointer to `int` wouldn't make sense unless there are actual integers of the same size at the location.

Comment: BTW what's wrong with type casting? You can't do much with a `void` pointer, you need to type cast it to something in order to work with the memory pointed by the void pointer..

Comment: Why at all do you have a `void*`? Why don't you simply define the type you need, and use a pointer to such a typed object? It looks like a poor software design.

Comment: ^^^ I was about to say much the same.  That is the usual way to use mapped or dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why are you trying to avoid casting a `void*`?

Comment: Your question says "Is it possible to set bits of a `void *` value?", but I think you mean "Is it possible to set bits *pointed to by* a `void *` value?".  This sets the bits of a `void *` value: `void *ptr = 0x1234;`.  This sets (or tries to set) some bits pointed to by that value: `*(unsigned char *)ptr = 0x56;`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to set those bits one by one without type casting them?

Yes.

Let us take advantage of:

> A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. C17dr § 6.2.5 28

Given `void *` and some *bit* index:

```
// No cast, access void * via union.
void set_bit_without_cast1(void *data, size_t bit_index) {
  union {
    void *vp;
    unsigned char *ucp;
  } u = { .vp = data };
  u.ucp[bit_index / CHAR_BIT] |= 1u << (bit_index % CHAR_BIT);
}
```

Or by simple assignment, no *cast* needed from `void *` to *object* pointer.

```
// No cast needed.
void set_bit_without_cast2(void *data, size_t bit_index) {
  unsigned char *ucp = data;
  ucp[bit_index / CHAR_BIT] |= 1u << (bit_index % CHAR_BIT);
}
```

---

OP has "I am pointing to the space via a `void*`".  Consider instead alternative code such so that "... pointing to the space via a `unsigned char *`" to simplify even further.

Answer (score 0):

`void*` are pointers to memory that can hold any data of any type that can fit in it. You don't want to leave your `void*` uncast because you cannot dereference it until it is at least implicitly cast to a pointer to a complete type.

To make a bitmap for a data field in one contiguous memory region, you want to create a structure with bitmap and data field members, and initialize a pointer to that structure with the return value of the `mmap()` call.

Here is a short example:

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 2048 //Pick whatever size you're mmaping (at least 16 bytes)

//One whole byte of bitmap and the 8 8-byte words it can map take up 65 bytes
#define MAP_LEN (CHUNK_SIZE % 65 ? CHUNK_SIZE / 65 + 1 : CHUNK_SIZE / 65)
//If MAP_LEN is not divisible by 8, we need padding between end of bitmap and beginning of data
#define DATA_LEN (MAP_LEN % 8 ? (CHUNK_SIZE - MAP_LEN - 8 + (MAP_LEN%8)) / 8 : (CHUNK_SIZE-MAP_LEN) / 8)

//This struct describes the layout of the whole mmap()ed region
struct chunk{
  uint8_t bitmap[MAP_LEN];  //Bitmap
  uint64_t data[DATA_LEN];  //8-byte words being mapped
};

int main(){
  struct chunk *mem = mmap(NULL,CHUNK_SIZE,/*Whatever your other mmap() parameters are*/);
  //Ensure mmap() didn't return (void*)-1
  memset(mem,0,CHUNK_SIZE); //This is only necessary if not mapped anonymously
  //Only the bitmap strictly must be cleared

  //Then store words like so
  mem->data[5] = 0xABADCAFE; //#5<-value (5 must be less than DATA_LEN)
  mem->bitmap[5/8] |= 1<<(5%8); //Put a 1 in the proper bit in the bitmap

  //And clear the bit when you're finished with its word
  mem->bitmap[5/8] &= ~(1<<(5%8));
}
```

Note: The above example uses the `MAP_LEN` and `DATA_LEN` macros at compile-time to calculate the greatest possible number of 8-byte words that can be stored and mapped within some `CHUNK_SIZE` number of bytes **with the assumption** that the alignment requirement of an 8-byte word is an 8-byte boundary, and on the condition that the bitmap must be the first thing in the allocated space, as per OP's prompt.